# Sum of Cells in Corner and in Center of Magic Square

Tags: combinatorics

For the magic square of order 4, the sum of 4 cells in each corner and sum of 4 cells in the center is the same which is equal to 34.

But I don't have idea how to prove it. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sum of the top row and bottom row and the sum of the middle two columns; they have to equal by the property of magic squares, and canceling out the overlapping squares should give you that the sum of $4$ corners and the sum of $4$ middle squares are equal. Elaborating a bit on this should give you that the sum is indeed $34$.

Comment: i can find that property but how to say that this two sum is 34 by using the property.

Comment: the sum of the 8 squares is the sum of the two diagonals.

Answer (score 0):

Try $$\pmatrix{2 & 15 & 12 & 5\cr 16 & 1 & 3 & 14\cr 9 & 8 & 6 & 11\cr 7 & 10 & 13 & 4\cr}$$

Comment: This is not a magic square as the sum of the diagonals are not equal to the sum of the rows and columns.

Comment: Depends on which definition of "magic square" you use.